# What is a macaroon?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am new to Linux and I got this message from Ubuntu One ([login.ubuntu.com](https://login.ubuntu.com/)):

> First time discharge for the macaroon

From the Account Activity tab ([login.ubuntu.com/activity](https://login.ubuntu.com/activity)):

```
Recent accesses made with your account are shown here.

This includes authentication requests made by other sites and devices.
Time/date   Type    IP address  User Agent/Browser
July 28, 2017, 11:12 a.m.   First time discharge for the macaroon   188.230.230.1   snapd/2.25 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.10.0-27-generic
July 28, 2017, 11:10 a.m.   New web login       Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"
```

What is this?

Comment: I will not write this as an answer (because it is NOT), but the answer lies just a Google search away from you... https://www.google.com/search?q=macaroon+ubuntu

Comment: Thank you dadexix86. I had checked google but at first I kind of missed what I was looking for. I have now found the answer.  PS - I have installed ubuntu 3 days ago and I am now learning things about computers which I never heard of before. I am already in love with linux! :)

Comment: @dadexix86 and now this SE question has taken first place on that Google search results page...

Answer (score 9):

From [Macaroons: Cookies with Contextual Caveats for Decentralized Authorization in the Cloud](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub41892.html) it seems to be a Google Research Project that:

- provides more flexible, decentralized cryptographic authorization credentials for Cloud services that support decentralized delegation
  between principals
- are based on a construction that uses nested, chained MACs (e.g., HMACs) in a manner that is highly efficient, easy to deploy, and widely applicable.
- embed caveats that attenuate and contextually confine
  when, where, by who, and for what purpose a target service
  should authorize requests.

**They are called "Macaroons" because they're a type of ["Cookie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)**

For more information: [read the blurb](https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/41892.pdf)...